# Django Templates - block inside an include, the block displays above or below, not in the block

Tags: django

I have inserted a block inside an include in hopes that I could references that block and add extra links to it if needed.

site_page.html:

```
{% extends 'home/sbadmin_base.html' %} 
{% load extras %} 
{% load static %} 
{% block content %}
{% include 'sites/site_tabs.html' %}
{% block extratabs %}
<li {{ active_sims|safe }}>
    <a href="{% url 'sites:site_overview' SiteID %}">Edit Site</a>
</li>
{% endblock %}
```

site_tabs.html

```
{% load extras %}
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li {{ active_ip|safe }}><a href="{% url 'sites:site_overview' SiteID %}">Overview</a>
    </li>
    <li {{ active_files|safe }}><a href="{% url 'sites:site_detail_files' SiteID %}">Files and Photos</a>
    </li>
    {% block extratabs %}
    {% endblock %}
</ul>
<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="ip">
            <div class="row">
```

When my page is rendered, the "extratabs" just appear below the include and outside the list as per the below:

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="/sites/site/7">Overview</a>
    </li>
    <li ><a href="/sites/site/files/7">Files and Photos</a>
    </li>

</ul>
<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="ip">
            <div class="row">

<li >
    <a href="/sites/site/7">Edit Site</a>
</li>
```

Comment: You can't override a block in a template that you include. See the note for the [include tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include) in the docs: *The include tag should be considered as an implementation of “render this subtemplate and include the HTML”, not as “parse this subtemplate and include its contents as if it were part of the parent”.*

Comment: is there an alternate way to achieve my goal?

Comment: It looks as if you could move the content of `site_tabs.html` to `home/sbadmin_base.html`, then continue to override the `extratabs` block in `site_page.html`.

Comment: I dont need site_tabs on all my pages though, how would not include the html in site tabs if I didn't need it? is there a djangoesque way of achieving such?

Comment: You could have a template `base_with_tabs` that extends `sbadmin_base.html`, and have your pages which have tabs extend that. Or add an if statement in the `sbadmin_base.html` and conditionally display the tabs.

Comment: how do I do the first option? The second option would fail as there would be variables missing from the templates that the tabs require

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment about missing variables. The first approach is the same idea as the "three level approach" [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance). The second 'section' template contains the tabs and the `extratabs` block, which can then be extended in the page template.

Comment: the site_tabs.html urls have 'SiteID' in them, which would only be available on pages with a SiteID. if that variable isnt available all the urls would cause a reverse lookup error. so I need them to only be there on site specific pages

Comment: But I suggested that you put them within an if statement, e.g. `{% if SiteID %}` or `{% if show_tabs %}` (and set `show_tabs` in your view). If the variable is not set, then you won't render those links so you won't get a reverse loopup error. Or if you use the "three level approach", then you only extend the tabs section template when you want to display them.

Comment: thanks, using your advice I have nested the templates with extends and have solved my issues